# Comparison between 2 columns in Pandas and printing only those rows that satisfy the condition

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code and I want to compare the `goals` and `xG` column and print only those rows which satisfy the condition `goals > xG`.

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 99999)
pd.set_option("max_rows", 99999)

url = "https://understat.com/league/EPL"

page_connect = urlopen(url)

page_html = BeautifulSoup(page_connect, "html.parser")

raw_string = page_html.findAll(name="script")[3].text

start_ind = raw_string.index("\\")

stop_ind = raw_string.index("')")

json_data = raw_string[start_ind:stop_ind]

json_data = json_data.encode("utf8").decode("unicode_escape")

final_json_df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(json_data))

a = final_json_df[final_json_df.shots == 0]

final_json_df = final_json_df.astype({"goals" : 'float'})

final_json_df = final_json_df.astype({"xG" : 'float'})
```

I tried this:

```
final_json_df[final_json_df.goals>xG]
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It would be helpful if someone can give the solution and explain why `final_json_df[final_json_df.goals>xG]` doesn't work.

Comment: `xG` doesn't seem to be defined. Did you mean `final_json_df['xG']`?

Comment: Yes, it worked now